# Updating Listview from Aysntask through adapter.add not working

Tags: listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I know similar questions have already been asked, however there doesn't seem to be a definite answer to updating a listview.

I am trying to update a Listview in the UI via a asynctask using arrayadapter.

I try to add the values to the adapter, however, while no error are given, it doesn't seem to work as the list view remains empty.

If I enter the array directly in the adapter, it works. But I want to do this through an asynctask for future development.

Not sure if it should be done through the progress update as below or in the PostExecute.

Here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myList;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private String[] names = {"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5"};


    //MAIN METHOD TO START PROGRAM
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);


        new MyTask().execute();
    }



    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            System.out.println("PreExecute Method Triggered");
            adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)myList.getAdapter();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            for (String Name : names)
            {
                publishProgress(Name);                    
            }            
            return "Values added";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            adapter.add(values[0]);
            System.out.println("OnProgress Method Triggered = " + values[0]);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println("PostExecute Method Triggered" + result);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my listview in my acivity_main.xml

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the adapter know to update the `ListView` because the underlying data has changed. You will need to call `notifydatasetchanged` to do this. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) for `ArrayAdapter`.

Add `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` after `add` in `onProgressUpdate()` or in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing that last command, but also found another line that was messing my code.

I had a this.recreate(); within the same method to refresh the screen.
That was clearing the listview exactly after populating it.